# Missing binary operator before token "#" error when #define is inside #if

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to define a macro `GCC_447_OR_LESS` (below) that I can use to check for instead of using the great a big ugly macro

```
#ifdef __linux__
    // Test for GCC 4.4.7 or less
    #if __GNUC__ < 4 ||                                                         \
        __GNUC__ == 4 && ( __GNUC_MINOR__ < 4 ||                                \
                         ( __GNUC_MINOR__ == 4 && __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ <= 7 ) )  \
        #define GCC_447_OR_LESS
    #endif
#endif
```

However I'm getting the error

```
error: missing binary operator before token "#"
 #define GCC_447_OR_LESS
 ^
```

I can't explain what's going on. Can't a #define be used within #if in the way I used it?

Comment: remove the last "\" in line `( __GNUC_MINOR__ == 4 && __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ <= 7 ) ) `

Comment: doh! Thanks @Raxvan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [character `\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765674/what-means-the-backslash-after-opening-bracket) tells the preprocessor that the current line is continued on the next. In your case the last if line `( __GNUC_MINOR__ == 4 && __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ <= 7 ) )  \` adds the define to the [#if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/conditional) condition.
The `#define` is part of the `true` block and must not be included in the `#if` line

Fixed code is:

```
#ifdef __linux__
    // Test for GCC 4.4.7 or less
    #if __GNUC__ < 4 ||                                                         \
        __GNUC__ == 4 && ( __GNUC_MINOR__ < 4 ||                                \
                         ( __GNUC_MINOR__ == 4 && __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ <= 7 ) ) /**/
        #define GCC_447_OR_LESS
    #endif
#endif
```